# Two Context Menu Sharing Icons but only one context menu icons shows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having two `Context Menus` like Below, both are having same `syntax` and are resources of different controls.

```
   <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}">
       <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
               <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
               <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTips}"/>
               <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
               <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Icon}"/>
               <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
           </Style>
       </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ContextMenu>
```

All works fine but only problem with Icon.

**ViewModel**

I have a property like below,

```
 public Image Icon
    {
        get { return _Icon; }
        set{ _Icon = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

I am initializing it like below,

```
   Icon = new Image
        {
            Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../images/ReIndex.png", UriKind.Relative)),
            Height = 20,
            Width = 20,
            Margin = new Thickness(5)
        };
```

The issue is that if one context menu shows the icon the other wont.

I know `MenuItem.Icon` is an `Object`. so i tried to using `BitmapImage` instead of `Image` directly but still i have the issue.

---

**Edit/Solved**

Added a resource like below,

```
 <Control.Resources>        
     <Image x:Shared="False" x:Key="Icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
 </Control.Resources>
```

Then My Context Menu looks like below,

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTips}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource Icon}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

**ViewModel** Now

```
public BitmapImage Icon
{
    get { return _Icon; }
    set{ _Icon = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../images/Pencil-01.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Main point is `x:Shared="False"` in the `Image` Control.

If any other good solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a resource like below,

```
<Control.Resources>        
    <Image x:Shared="False" x:Key="Icon" Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="20" Width="20"/>
</Control.Resources>
```

Then My Context Menu looks like below,

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Actions}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroMenuItem}">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTips}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource Icon}"/>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding CommandParameter}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public BitmapImage Icon
{
   get { return _Icon; }
   set{ _Icon = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}

Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"../images/Pencil-01.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Main point is `x:Shared="False"` in the `Image` Control.